# To get the custom type post "name" and "label" only

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using the code below to get the post name and post label. But I don't want all the custom types like "post", "page" and "attachment."  I need the custom post types "name" and "label" only.

```
  $types = get_post_types( array( 'exclude_from_search' => false ), 'objects' ); ?>

          <?php foreach ( $types as $type )
            {
              echo '<li>' . $type->name . '</li>';
              echo '<li>' . $type->singular_label . '</li>';
              }
          ?>
```

How can I get the custom post type "name" and "label" only?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
'public'   => true,
'_builtin' => false
```

to your arguments like so:

```
$types = get_post_types( array( 'exclude_from_search' => false, 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false ), 'objects' );
```

This should then only display your custom post type(s).

Comment: Just a note - he'll still have to check the resulting array, because plugins can also register post types.